# foreign key doens't post when submitting the form in Laravel vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have two tables:

Table one(parties):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->string('ic_passport');
        $table->string('nationality');
        $table->string('income_tax_no');
        $table->string('income_Tax_filing_branch');
        $table->string('phone_no');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Table two(corraddresses):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('corraddresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('party_id');
        $table->foreign('party_id')->references('id')->on('parties');
        $table->string('address_1');
        $table->string('address_2');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('poscode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Model one(Party):

```
class Party extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['full_name','ic_passport','nationality','income_tax_no',
'income_Tax_filing_branch','phone_no','email'];
}
```

Model two(Corraddress):

```
class Corraddress extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['address_1','address_2','city','poscode'];
}
```

Controller one(PartyController - Store function):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $party = Party::create($request->post());
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Party Created Successfully!!',
        'party'=>$party
    ]);
}
```

Controller two(CorraddressController - Store function):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $corraddress = Corraddress::create($request->post());
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Corraddress Created Successfully!!',
        'corraddress'=>$corraddress
    ]);
}
```

in the view i am submitting one form only to post the data in two different tables so what i am trying to do while submitting the form "parties" will be posted and after that "corraddresses" will be posted and assign the primary key from "parties" to "corraddresses" as a foreign key

the view is below:

```
data() {
return {
full_name: '',
ic_passport: '',
nationality: '',
income_tax_no: '',
income_Tax_filing_branch: '',
phone_no: '',
email: '',

address_1: '',
address_2: '',
city: '',
poscode: '',
};
},
methods: {
addNewPost(){
            axios.post('/api/auth/party',{
                full_name: this.full_name,
                ic_passport: this.ic_passport,
                nationality: this.nationality,
                income_tax_no: this.income_tax_no,
                income_Tax_filing_branch: this.income_Tax_filing_branch,
                phone_no: this.phone_no,
                email: this.email,
            })
            axios.post('/api/auth/corraddress',{
                address_1: this.address_1,
                address_2: this.address_2,
                city: this.city,
                poscode: this.poscode,
            })
            .then((response)=>{
                this.$router.push({name:"database-management"})
            $('#success').html(response.data.message)
            })
},
},
```

so in the case above the data for "parties" will be posted but it doesn't post anything for "corraddresses"

[image]

but when i tried to post the form without assigning foreign key it will post in both tables

is there an issue with my approach regarding the foreign key? or any extra steps that i didn't do?

Comment: You're not informing your `corraddress` endpoint which `party` to associate the incoming `request` with. Either supply it as part of the request or really, combine the two endpoints into a single endpoint that performs the creation of both objects in an [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) manner.

Comment: how would that approach be in migration?

Comment: Your migration is fine. As I said, you're API requests are not associating resources.

Answer (score 0):

You receive a 500 error because the column `party_id` is not nullable, and so the insert in database fails.
You always have to send it when creating a new corraddress or you can set it as nullable

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('party_id')->nullable();
```

I suggest you a more elegant way to define that foreign id:

```
$table->foreignId('party_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained('parties')
                ->cascadeOnDelete()
                ->cascadeOnUpdate();
```

Another suggestion is to set in the .env file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

To receive more details from laravel when an error occurs.

EDIT:

```
axios.post('/api/auth/party',{
                full_name: this.full_name,
                ic_passport: this.ic_passport,
                nationality: this.nationality,
                income_tax_no: this.income_tax_no,
                income_Tax_filing_branch: this.income_Tax_filing_branch,
                phone_no: this.phone_no,
                email: this.email,
            }).then(response => {
              axios.post('/api/auth/corraddress',{
                  address_1: this.address_1,
                  address_2: this.address_2,
                  city: this.city,
                  poscode: this.poscode,
                  party_id: response.party.id
              })
            }
```

Sorry I'm not so used with axios

Comment: i appreciate the help but now it post in both tables but in "corraddresses" it show the "party_id" as NULL so it didn't take the primary key from "Parties" and posted in "corraddresses" as foreign key, why? i commented `$table->unsignedBigInteger('party_id');` and `$table->foreign('party_id')->references('id')->on('parties');` and added your way to the migration. is there anything wrong that preventing the foreign key from posting?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my answer wasn't clear enough. The real problem is that in your second request you have to add the party_id, you are not providing it at all. From the first request you can retrieve the party id from the output json, then send it in the second request:
axios.post('/api/auth/corraddress',{
                address_1: this.address_1,
                address_2: this.address_2,
                city: this.city,
                poscode: this.poscode,
                party_id: partyId
            })

Comment: i applied the above to the second request and now it post the data in "parties" only and it doesn't do anything to "corraddresses"

Comment: If you console log the response from the first request, are you able to retrieve the party id?

Comment: this is what i'm getting from response: `{"message":"Party Created Successfully!!","party":{"full_name":"test","ic_passport":"test","nationality":"test","income_tax_no":"test","income_Tax_filing_branch":"test","phone_no":"test","email":"test","updated_at":"2022-11-04T08:28:09.000000Z","created_at":"2022-11-04T08:28:09.000000Z","id":1}}`

Comment: Ok so you have the id, if you're able to retrieve it from the json, you can send it in the second request for creating the corraddress. "party_id" also needs to be added in attribute $fillable of Corraddress model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249316/discussion-between-valkoff-and-sam).

Comment: i have moved to chat